# How do people build applications with office or VS GUI/functionality? Are there libraries for this?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ms-office, libraries

I often run into non-microsoft software that has the same look and functionality as microsoft office or visual studio. How do people build this? Surely they don't create everything from scratch?

Examples:

Office:

https://www.royalapplications.com/ts/win/features

https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/dax-studio/

Visual Studio:

https://www.sapien.com/software/wmiexplorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably use **Application Frameworks** of some sort.

DevExpress sell one, called XAF

Link [here](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/)

I think there are a few on the market